# Has Anyone Used Lenis with Jekyll?

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I'm trying to use a scroll smoother on Jekyll and it's not working. The page just freezes and lags. The hardest thing about it is that there's no error on the console, so I can't debug it. I can't report it because Jekyll won't run on CodeSandbox. I'm not sure if it's the scroll smoother or Jekyll.

I've tried using it in a WordPress page with the same settings and it works. That's why I'm convinced that it's Jekyll.

Here's how I'm loading it:

```
const lenis = new Lenis({
  smoothWheel: true,
  smoothTouch: true
});

lenis.on('scroll', ScrollTrigger.update);

gsap.ticker.add((time)=>{
  lenis.raf(time * 1000)
});

gsap.ticker.lagSmoothing(0);
```